# Adact wordpress menu to bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-4

I want my menu to stay that way.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio
      <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nosotros</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contactanos</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I try to do it as follows

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <?php 
    wp_nav_menu([
      'container'      => false,
      'items_wrap'     => '%3$s',
      'theme_location' => 'menu_top'               
    ]);
  ?>
</ul>
```

on file `functions.php`

```
<?php 

register_nav_menus([
   'menu_top' => 'Menu superior'
]);

?>
```

but what I achieve with this is to get the following

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-4"><a href="#">inicio</a></li>
</ul>
```

as I do to place the classes I want, and as I do to specify that an option is `active`. I'm using bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you can collect your menu's items and print them with a foreach:

```
<?php
  $currentURL         = home_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );                      
  $menuItemCollection = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'menu_top' );
?>

<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <?php foreach ( $menuItemCollection as $menuItem ): ?>
    <?php $activeClass = ($menuItem->url == $currentURL) ? ' active' : ''; ?>

    <li class="nav-item<?php echo $activeClass; ?>">
      <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo $menuItem->url; ?>">                                        
        <?php echo $menuItem->title; ?>
      </a>
    </li>

  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried your code, but doing this `wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'menu_top' );` comes up null, some idea.

Comment: Do you have any items in `Menu superior` on admin?

Comment: ya lo resolvi, gracias